# Get Information from the android status bar

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I was wondering if its possible to pull information from the android status bar. For example the pandora app or the google navigation display information in the status bar when they are running in the background, my app can launch those apps and it would be nice to have a display for say the current song playing in pandora in my app.

So is there any way to get data from the status bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app has access only to its own notifications. It has no rights to read other apps notifs.

Comment: Thats what I thought but wasnt sure, was kinda hoping since you could send notifications you might be able to pull them as well. oh well guess that feature wont happen.  Thanks